# Deciding length of shapefile fields?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, length

At my work have inherited several shapefiles that originate from MapInfo that I am bringing into a new project in QGIS. I have the opportunity to change the column names, add and subtract columns and because there is not too much data in them yet I can start afresh and adjust the field lengths too.

I notice that some of the field lengths are a lot bigger than they need to be and I remember from past database creation 20 years ago, or so, that it is best to keep the field lengths to be no longer than they need to be to save on 'space', to improve efficiency.

Is this still desirable or does the field length not matter anymore?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer depends on data format. dBase-III+ files, which are used in shapefiles for attributes, are fixed-width, so defining a FIPS column to be 254 width text uses 254 bytes.  Worse yet, dBase has a maximum record width of 4000 bytes, so the 249 wasted on a five character field aren't available for other fields (of which there is a maximum of 100 or 255, depending on who's implementing the standard).  Limits also apply to the total size of the dBase file (2Gb), which could be approached by a 536k records at maximum width, when 5.36m records would be available at 400 byte width.

There is another reason to limit field width -- data quality.  If a designator can only legally hold two characters, but you define it with ten, then you increase the possibility of having a fat-fingered invalid value accepted by the data file.

On the other hand, if you provide only the width necessary, and get international data in UTF-8 format, you may find yourself short on space when a *character* can use 2-6 bytes.

So, for database string fields (which includes file geodatabase), that are generally terminated, and therefore don't waste row space, flexibility is an option, but for fixed-width formats the old rules still apply.